# How to compare date between 2 tibbles?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

```
mydf<-data.frame(x=as.Date("2017-1-1"))
mydf[1,1]-as.Date("2017-10-16")
```

`Time difference of -288 days`

```
mytb<-tibble(x=as.Date("2017-1-1"))
mytb[1,1]-as.Date("2017-10-16")
```

`Error in mytb[1, 1] - as.Date("2017-10-16") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "-.Date") for "-"`

How to compare the date in tibble? I have a solution: convert tibble to dataframe, but is there any more feasible idea?

Comment: Not very clean but do the trick:  mytb$x[1] - as.Date("2017-10-16")

Comment: @Flo.P Your comments are part of the answer below, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is potentially a difference in behavior between `data.frame` vs. `tibble/data_frame`.  With `data.frame`, the `drop = TRUE`

```
mydf[1,1]
#[1] "2017-01-01"
```

changes the `data.frame` to a `vector` when there is subsetting of single row/column etc.

But, it is not the case with `tibble`

```
mytb[1,1]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  x         
#   <date>    
#1 2017-01-01
```

It is still a `tibble`.  So we need to extract it with either `$` or `[[`

```
mytb[['x']][1]
#[1] "2017-01-01"
```

The `tidyverse` option would be `pull`

```
mytb %>%
     pull(x) %>%
     magrittr::extract(1) %>%
     magrittr::subtract(as.Date("2017-10-16"))
#Time difference of -288 days
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I just wanna know how to convert a tibble to vector.

Comment: @wasmetqall  You can use `unlist` or if it is a single column tibble, either `mytb$x` or `mytb[['x']]` would do it